# Creating salt with Portable PHP password hashing framework

Tags: php, hash, hashcode, password-protection, salt-creation

I'd like to use [Portable PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) to hash passwords. But I find that its demos don't use salt for hashing a password. But it use a dummy salt for checking password which I find it strange and I don't understand this idea at all,

```
$dummy_salt = '$2a$08$1234567890123456789012';

if (isset($dummy_salt) && strlen($hash) < 20)
        $hash = $dummy_salt;
```

I wonder, if I want to use convention method which I can generate the unique salt and store it for each user in my database, how can I use Portable PHP password hashing framework to generate salts?

This is the function I use to hash passwords but I have been told that sha512 has the same issue as sha1, wise to trust the expert like Portable PHP password hashing framework,

```
function hash_sha512($phrase,&$salt = null)
{
    //$pepper = '!@#$%^&*()_+=-{}][;";/?<>.,';

    if ($salt == '')
    {
        $salt = substr(hash('sha512',uniqid(rand(), true).PEPPER_KEY.microtime()), 0, SALT_LENGTH);
    }
    else
    {
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, SALT_LENGTH);
    }

    return hash('sha512',$salt.PEPPER_KEY.$phrase);
}
```

Let me know if you have any idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [phpass article](http://www.openwall.com/articles/PHP-Users-Passwords) linked to from that page:

> Besides the actual hashing, phpass
>   transparently generates random salts
>   when a new password or passphrase is
>   hashed, and it encodes the hash type,
>   the salt, and the password stretching
>   iteration count into the "hash
>   encoding string" that it returns. When
>   phpass authenticates a password or
>   passphrase against a stored hash, it
>   similarly transparently extracts and
>   uses the hash type identifier, the
>   salt, and the iteration count out of
>   the "hash encoding string". **Thus, you
>   do not need to bother with salting and
>   stretching on your own - phpass takes
>   care of these for you**.

...so it's not surprising that the examples don't use salting! You may be over-seasoning your code.

The code sample with the dummy salt is an example of how to prevent a timing attack by making sure that whether a user exists or not, the validation of the user takes the same amount of time, effectively by doing a dummy authentication for non-existent users. It needs a dummy salt because if the user doesn't exist, it won't have a stored salt to use.

Comment: thanks. should I use the dummy salt for preventing the timing attack then?

Comment: @lauthiamkok That's up to you, really, and depends on the rest of your setup. For example, if your website will allow people to add new accounts and tells them if a username they choose already exists, then there's not much point preventing an attacker working the same thing out with an authentication timing attack!